Is 3-phenyl-1H-pyrazole more electron deficient or rich?
More specifically, will the Minisci reaction work here? I know the NH has its lone pair in the ring and is electron rich, and the N=C has its lone pair out of the ring and is electron poor, but which wins out when you have both?


I doubt it would work :/

N's lone pair is delocalized heavily on account of the aromaticity of the ring. If you draw the resonating structures you realize that each carbon in the lower ring has a minus charge. Of course resonance wins..

A "Minisci reaction" on 3-phenyl-1H-pyrazole would be positive that would involve a nucleophilic radical substitution at the carbon atom adjacent to the nitrogen in the pyrazole ring, but reaction might need modified reagent instead of usual. For example, Google search has given a review of recent advances in Minisci reaction (Ref. 1) that cites only one heterocycle closely resemble to 1H-pyrazole, 2-amino-1,3,4-thiadiazole, which undergoes Minisci reaction  (difluoromethyl addition to heterocycle)
The original article has shown 21 different heterocycles with successful Minisci reaction (see above image with satisfactory yields) under specific conditions (Ref. 2).

References:

Rupert S. J. Proctor and Robert J. Phipps, "Recent Advances in Minisci-Type Reactions," Angew. Chem. Intl. Ed. 2019, 58(39), 13666-13699 (DOI:  https://doi.org/10.1002/anie.201900977).
Yuta Fujiwara, Janice A. Dixon, Rodrigo A. Rodriguez, Ryan D. Baxter, Darryl D. Dixon, Michael R. Collins, Donna G. Blackmond, and Phil S. Baran, "A New Reagent for Direct Difluoromethylation," J. Am. Chem. Soc. 2012, 134(3), 1494–1497 (DOI: https://doi.org/10.1021/ja211422g).

